# Show message if javascript is not enabled in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I'm looking for a solution to show the visitor of my website an info message, if he has no javascript enabled. I tried it with a message in a div, that is visible by default but immediately hidden by a jQuery function on start up. The problem is, that the message is visible for a short time (until it is hidden), what is very irritating.

Are there other ways to show a message, if JS is not enabled?

Thanks,
Konrad

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use the `noscript` tag:

```
<noscript>

  <div class="awesome-fancy-styling">
    This site requires JavaScript. I will only be visible if you have it disabled.
  </div>
  ...
</noscript>
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/noscript.

Comment: There should be a category for "gimme" questions… oh, I guess `[Duplicate]`. ;-)

Comment: Given the use of browser extensions such as NoScript which selectively block JS without disabling it in the browser, the use of the `<noscript>` element isn't very effective.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `noscript`, inside these tags is what will display if the user has javascript disabled.

If you want to hide the other content if the user doesn't have javascript enabled, you can do something like so (this uses jquery):

```
<style type="text/css">
    .example {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.example').show();
    });
</script>

<div class="example">
    <p>...</p>
</div>

<noscript>
    <p>You must have javascript enabled for the example div to show!</p>
</noscript>
```

This will only show the content if the user has javascript enabled.

Comment: This is the most usefull answer because sometimes you want just to hide content of webtemplates providing alternatives for no-javascript (so instead of a overlay image with the "x" button, with no javascript you just open a new page with URL)

Answer (score 2):

There is never a need to use `<noscript>` tags with browsers more recent than IE4 and Netscape 4. All that is needed is to use `JavaScript` to hide anything in the page that you don’t want those with `javaScript` enabled to see. This is way more flexible than `<noscript>` since you can actually test for the browser supporting specific `JavaScript` commands using feature sensing and only hide the `HTML` when the features that your `JavaScript` requires to work are actually supported properly by the browser.

```
<p align=center id=js_disabled_message>
    x.com requires JavaScript Enabled <br> <a href="https://www.enable-javascript.com/">www.enable-javascript.com</a>
</p>
<script>
    document.getElementById('js_disabled_message').style.display = 'none';
</script>
```

The above code will hide the `p` tag, **only** if `js` is enabled.
It's kinda of the opossite logic to detect if `JavaScript` is enabled and it works well on all browsers.

[SRC](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/alert-enable-javascript/5100/5)

Answer (score 0):

You can use '' and provide the error message you want.

```
    <html>
    <body>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        document.write("Hello World!")
     //-->
    </script>

    <noscript>
     Sorry...JavaScript is needed to go ahead.
    </noscript>

    </body>
    </html>
```